# What does it means when velocity is undetermined?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, velocity

The original problem is that a car goes into a curve that has a slope of 45° and $\mu$=1 and I need to get the maximum and minimum speed of the car to not slide up or down.
Doing my analysis I got two equations to get those velocities but... when I put $(\mu=1)$ and $(\theta=\frac{\pi}{4})$, I get the minimum velocity as a complex number and the maximum velocity is simply undetermined. The formulas I ended up with are these:

$$v_{min}=\sqrt{Rg \left( \frac{\sin\theta-\mu \cos\theta}{\cos\theta-\mu \sin\theta}\right)}$$
$$v_{max}=\sqrt{Rg \left( \frac{\sin\theta+\mu \cos\theta}{\cos\theta-\mu \sin\theta}\right)}$$

My teacher said that my analysis is correct and they gave us those values in purpose, so I just need to know what does it mean.

Comment: The maximum and minimum speed of what? Any faster/slower and the car will start sliding?

Comment: Yes, I edited it anyways. Thanks

Comment: Check to see of the car slides at 0 velocity.  I suspect that it will not.  Also, note that in the limit as the angle approaches 45 degrees, the velocity goes to infinity, which means that there is no upper limit on the sliding velocity.

Comment: Make sure those values you are plugging in do not violate the assumptions under which you formulated those equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some general guidance. Whenever you solve equations to find parameters, and then the math gives no or a nonsensical answer, go back to the physics of the problem.

You get no meaningful answer for the minimum speed. So, what would be the most extreme case you can have for the minimum speed? It's zero, because that's where there's no centrifugal force to counter the sliding inwards. So when you get no answer from the equation, ask yourself "Is this even possible in the most extreme case?". To verify, check manually from more basic equations whether the car will slide at a standstill. If it does not, your answer for the minimum speed is 0. (If you find that it does slide, your math is wrong somewhere.)

For the maximum, it's a little harder to see. As a first guess (seeing that the formula gives no answer) you can try calculating the sliding manually for larger and larger speeds. If you always see the same pattern of the same terms cancelling out and there is no sliding, you can become convinced that indeed there is no maximum speed; the car will never slide, no matter how fast you go.  Of course, that's not a rigorous proof, but as a basic "does this make sense?" check, it can be enough.

Comment: I did it, when the velocity is 0, the car does not slide. For the maximum velocity I found that, if we look at the forces acting over the vertical axis (asuming the car isn't moving), when mu=1 and the angle is 45°, the conclusion is that the weight must be 0. As it is false, then the hypothesis is incorrect, therefore the car must move if there is any centrifugal force. Thank you.